# Let $X$, $Y$ are dependent, are $X+\epsilon_1$ $Y+\epsilon_2$ Independent? Uncorrelated?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence, correlation

Let $X,Y$ be two dependent random variables.

Let $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2$ be two independent draws from a normal distribution.

**Are $X+\epsilon_1$, $Y+\epsilon_2$ independent? Or at least uncorrelated?** Or maybe it depends?

---

Ex: Suppose twice between 10-11am we ask someone the time of day, and that the second time we ask is 1 minute after the first time we ask.

Let $X$ be the RV for their first answer, and $Y$ the RV for their second answer, and $x,y$ denote the respective realizations

(and suppose only minutes matter, not seconds, so t˙ere are only 60 possible values for $x$)

Then $X,Y$ are dependent because $y=x+1$ always.

Suppose, however, that they report the time with some error, drawn from a normal distribution. That is, we observe $Z_1=x+\epsilon_1$, $Z_2=y+\epsilon_2$, where $\epsilon_i$ is the error the ith time we ask.

Are $Z_1,Z_2$ independent? or uncorrelated?

---

My brief thoughts:

I try to think about this, but if the error, $\epsilon_i$ is small, then $Z_2\sim Z_1+1$, which makes me think $Z_1,Z_2$ are correlated, but if the error is big, then they would look uncorrelated? (but even then their distributions I think are dependent? because $X$ is effectively "centering" $Z_2$?)

However... I'm pretty sure if we observed $Z_3=5+\epsilon_1$, $Z_4=5+\epsilon_2$, these would be independent... which makes me confused... why adding a constant is different from adding a realization from a random variable...

Comment: My first thought is that they will still be dependent, but less correlated.  The correlation will be "diluted" by the error terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle your last question first:

Adding a constant to two independent error terms means they are still independent.

Adding the *same* random variable to two independent error terms means the results are dependent.

Two different, correlated random variables added to two independent error terms will be correlated.

Now for a calculation: start with

$$Cor(Z_1, Z_2) = E[ Z_1Z_2] - E[ Z_1 ]E[ Z_2]$$

expand it all out, use that $Cor(X,Y) = 1$, and you will get a nonzero answer.

Answer (score 3):

By linearity of [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance),
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X+\epsilon_1, Y+\epsilon_2) = \mathrm{cov}(X, Y) + \mathrm{cov}(X, \epsilon_2) + \mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_1, Y) + \mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)
$$
Since $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are independent, last term is zero. So, correlation of $X+\epsilon_1$ and $Y+\epsilon_2$ depends on correlation between $X$ and $Y$ as well correlations between $X$ and $\epsilon_1$, $Y$ and $\epsilon_2$. If
$\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) + \mathrm{cov}(X, \epsilon_2) + \mathrm{cov}(\epsilon_1, Y) \neq 0$, $X+\epsilon_1$ and $Y+\epsilon_2$ are correlated and hence dependent.
Otherwise, they are uncorrelated, but it doesn't say anything about dependence. However, if $X$ and $Y$ are constants, then $X+\epsilon_1$ and $Y+\epsilon_2$ both follow normal distribution and are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ are also independent from $X$ and $Y$
Assuming (for simplicity but not needed) also that $E[\varepsilon_1] = E[\varepsilon_2] = 0$ then you can see using directly the definition of **Covariance** and linearity of the Expectation operator:

$$
Cov[Z_1,Z_2] = E[Z_1,Z_2] - E[Z_1]E[Z_2]
$$

From this, with the assumptions:

$$
E[Z_1,Z_2] = E[X_1X_2] + E[X_1\varepsilon_2] + E[X_2\varepsilon_1] + E[\varepsilon_1\varepsilon_2] = E[X_1X_2] \\
E[Z_1]E[Z_2] = E[X_1]E[X_2] 
$$

So with this:

$$
Cov(Z_1,Z_2) = E[X_1X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2] = Cov(X_1.X_2)
$$

So, with this you can see that if $X_1, X_2$ are **correlated** then $Z_1,Z_2$ are too, and this also implies that they are also **dependent**